# Python click every point inside a 200px x 200px square

Tags: python

I want to make a python script that clicks every point inside a 200px x 200px square. I'm using a library that's called pyautogui and I tried to do it, but it didn't work as fine as I would like. Mouse only clicks in the middle of the screen. How can I fix that?
Here is a photo of the square and then there is the code that I actually have.
[200px x 200px square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlphm.png)

Code:

```py
import pyautogui
import time


time.sleep(5)

exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False


x=700
y=400

for i in range(500):
    if x <= 900 and y <= 400:
        x= x + 1
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        time.sleep(0.001)

    else:
        x = 700
        y = 460

    if x <= 900 and y <= 460:
        x= x + 140
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        time.sleep(0.001)

    else:
        x = 700
        y = 520

    if x <= 900 and y <= 520:
        x= x + 1
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        time.sleep(0.001)

    else:
        x = 700
        y = 580

    if x <= 900 and y <= 580:
        x= x + 1
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        time.sleep(0.001)

    else:
        x = 700
        y = 600

    if x <= 900 and y <=600:
        x= x + 1
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        time.sleep(0.001)
    else:
        print("finish")
```

PD: I know that my code is very weird, I put the if and the else conditions because I want to be sure that the program clicks by a horizontal mode, no in digonal, I'm new programming jeje.

Comment: You are never updating the `x` and `y` values, and they are always set to `x=700` and `y=400`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler approach might be what you need.  Create arrays of your x and y values, then a pair of for loops will build every point in your 200x200 rectangle and you can click at that point.

```
xs = range(700,700+200)
ys = range(400,400+200)

for x in xs: 
    for y in ys:
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

Comment: Yeah! That is exactly how I want! But... it goes too slow, I tried to put sleep(0.0001) and it goes a little bit faster. However, it's still too slow, how can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried remove the sleep calls? In a 200x200 grid you'd be calling that 40,000 times which equates to approximately 4 seconds of just sleeping.

Comment: If you are looking for speed then you definitely don't want to use `sleep()`, the code as written in my answer should be all you need.  To speed up what's in my question you can do 2 things.  1. you can click faster than pyautogui, I do not know of a way to do this, but it might exist.  2. if you can't click faster click less.  Do you really need to click EVERY pixel or would, say, every 5 pixels do for a 25x speed increase?

Comment: I actually used  a pyautogui method, it's pyautogui.PAUSE = 0 and now it clicks much faster. Thank you!